# Firing onload property when .js file is inserted dynamically

Tags: javascript

I fire my javascript using the onload property -> `window.onload = function(){ // start code }`

Rececently I started doing an .innerHTML write to the `<head>` tag which sets my .js file.

`document.head.innerHTML = html_string`

```
// where html_string contains the link to my .js file.
```

Problem I'm having is that now the onload function is never called so my page has no javascript on it.

Is there a way to manually call it or emulate its behavior?

Comment: why would you want this? Why nou write the link?

Comment: Why did you do that? It worked fine before the change, it doesn't work after the change, did I hear **rollback**?

Comment: One guess it that .innerHTML writes have no effect on what the browser would call a load event....the first thing I could try is simply call the function at the top of my code in place of setting the property...but manually firing it by placing some embedded code at the end of the document would make more sense.

Comment: **It seems like you know the problem and you know how to solve it. What is your question??**

Comment: Well I guess i answered it myself...just call the function at the bottom of the html document in embedded form...this will ensure the dom is loaded...should emulate it perfectly..with one line of code.

Comment: this does not work for some reason.

Comment: the inserted embedded javascript does not run either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't insert the scripts by setting the `innerHTML` of `document.head`. Add a `<script>` DOM node and listen for its load event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102718/1048572, [Capturing onload event when dynamically loading .js files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1917953/1048572), [jQuery event that triggers after CSS is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2571164/1048572)